# wxPython: Class attribute shared among several instances accidentally

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, wxpython

This bit of code has me scratching my head.

I'm trying to write wxPython GUI, with a frame that contains several 'PulseBox' objects (code below). Each pulse box is basically 4 wx.TextCtrls with 4 wx.StaticTexts positioned next to them as labels. The object has a single attribute called 'data' which is a dictionary that I would like to access later.

I would like the TextCtrls to change the values of 'data' for their own pulse box when text is entered. Unfortunatley, when I enter text into a single pulse box, it is now changing 'data' for all the pulseboxes.

```
import wx

class MainGUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, '')

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        #Create Controls
        #All Contained in a Static Box       
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)        

        #A Row of Pulseboxes
        self.setpulse = PulseBox(self.panel, 'Set')
        self.resetpulse = PulseBox(self.panel, 'Reset')
        self.gatepulse = PulseBox(self.panel, 'Gate')

        #Generate Layout
        #Use a FlexGrid Sizer
        self.fgs = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=1, cols=3, vgap=15, hgap=15)

        self.fgs.AddMany([(self.setpulse, 1, wx.EXPAND),
            (self.resetpulse, 1, wx.EXPAND),
            (self.gatepulse, 1, wx.EXPAND)])

        #Add the FlexGridSizer to the StaticBoxSizer
        self.sizer.Add(self.fgs, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL, border=15)

        #FitTheSizer
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.sizer.Fit(self)



class PulseBox(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, name='Set', 

        data=dict(Leading='1.0e-6', Width='10.0e-6',
            Trailing='1.0e-6', Delay='1.0e-3') ):

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.data = data
        self.name = name

        #Create Controls
        #All Contained in a Static Box       
        self.box = wx.StaticBox(self, label=name + ' Pulse (seconds)')
        self.sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.box, wx.VERTICAL)        

        #A row of labels
        self.label_lead = wx.StaticText(self, label='Leading')
        self.label_width = wx.StaticText(self, label='Width')
        self.label_trail = wx.StaticText(self, label='Trailing')
        self.label_delay = wx.StaticText(self, label='Delay')

        #A row of textctrls
        self.textctrl_lead = wx.TextCtrl(self, value=data['Leading'], style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER, name='Leading')
        self.textctrl_width = wx.TextCtrl(self, value=data['Width'], style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER, name='Width')
        self.textctrl_trail = wx.TextCtrl(self, value=data['Trailing'], style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER, name='Trailing')
        self.textctrl_delay = wx.TextCtrl(self, value=data['Delay'], style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER, name='Delay')

        #Send back their data
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.on_change_pulses, self.textctrl_width)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.on_change_pulses, self.textctrl_lead)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.on_change_pulses, self.textctrl_trail)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.on_change_pulses, self.textctrl_delay)


        #Generate Layout
        #Use a FlexGrid Sizer
        self.fgs = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=4, cols=2, vgap=9, hgap=25)

        self.fgs.AddMany([(self.label_lead), (self.textctrl_lead, 1, wx.EXPAND),
            (self.label_width), (self.textctrl_width, 1, wx.EXPAND),
            (self.label_trail), (self.textctrl_trail, 1, wx.EXPAND),
            (self.label_delay), (self.textctrl_delay, 1, wx.EXPAND)])

        #Expand the TextCtrl boxes to fill panel
        self.fgs.AddGrowableCol(1, 1)

        #Add the FlexGridSizer to the StaticBoxSizer
        self.sizer.Add(self.fgs, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, border=15)

        #FitTheSizer
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.sizer.Fit(self)

    def on_change_pulses(self, event):
        textctrl = event.GetEventObject()
        name = textctrl.GetName()
        value = textctrl.GetValue()

        self.data[name] = value

        print self.name, self.data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    app.frame = MainGUI()
    app.frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

As an example, when I change the 'Leading' TextCtrl of the 'Set' box

> to 1, I get printed: Set {'Delay': '1.0e-3', 'Width': '10.0e-6',
>   'Trailing': '1.0e-6', 'Leading': u'1'}

And then when I change the 'Width' TextCtrl of the 'Reset' box to 2, I get printed:

> Reset {'Delay': '1.0e-3', 'Width': u'2', 'Trailing': '1.0e-6',
>   'Leading': u'1'}

Even though I never set the 'Leading' for the Reset box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are processing the message `EVT_TEXT_ENTER` and `on_change_pulses` is only updating `self.data` with the value of `TextCtrl` that revised the event.

You can fix it either by processing `EVT_TEXT` so the values are updated as soon as the user modifies some `TextCtrl`, you can add:

```
        ....
        #Send back their data
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.on_change_pulses, self.textctrl_width)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.on_change_pulses, self.textctrl_lead)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.on_change_pulses, self.textctrl_trail)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.on_change_pulses, self.textctrl_delay)

        # ADDED: listen for EVT_TEXT event
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.on_change_pulses_update, self.textctrl_width)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.on_change_pulses_update, self.textctrl_lead)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.on_change_pulses_update, self.textctrl_trail)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT, self.on_change_pulses_update, self.textctrl_delay)

        #Generate Layout
        #Use a FlexGrid Sizer
        self.fgs = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows=4, cols=2, vgap=9, hgap=25)
        ....
```

and add a handler to the event:

```
    def on_change_pulses_update(self, event):
        textctrl = event.GetEventObject()
        name = textctrl.GetName()
        value = textctrl.GetValue()

        self.data[name] = value
```

or you can re-read the values of all `TextCtrl` if anyone of them revised `EVT_TEXT_ENTER`:

```
    def on_change_pulses(self, event):
        textctrl = event.GetEventObject()
        name = textctrl.GetName()
        #value = textctrl.GetValue()

        self.data['Width']    = self.textctrl_width.GetValue()
        self.data['Leading']  =  self.textctrl_lead.GetValue()
        self.data['Trailing'] = self.textctrl_trail.GetValue()
        self.data['Delay']    =  self.textctrl_delay.GetValue()

        print self.name, self.data
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. I ended up using the second version as it was more explicit and easier to read.